# Need help understanding confusing info in tax publication

Tags: negation, legalese

My English is not very good since I came to the country few years ago.  I want to prepare taxes and I am just looking at some information from IRS publication 970.  In particular, can someone please explain to me simply what the following passage means from the publication.

> A scholarship or fellowship grant is tax free only to the
>   extent:
>   It doesn't exceed your qualified education expenses;
>   It isn't designated or earmarked for other purposes
>   (such as room and board), and doesn't require (by its
>   terms) that it can't be used for qualified education expenses;
>   and
>   It doesn't represent payment for teaching, research, or
>   other services required as a condition for receiving the
>   scholarship. For exceptions, see Payment for services,
>   later.

In particular, I am confused by phrase "It isn't designated or earmarked for other purposes (such as room and board)."  So If I receive a scholarship for $2000 for room or board, it is taxable?

Comment: You understand this correctly: any grant (or portion of a grant) which is designated for non-education expenses is taxable.

Comment: You can google qualified education expenses. Those are the only deductible ones. Room and board are subject to a cap.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the *language* used (not the legal issues), I would simplify it down to the part in question.

> A scholarship or fellowship grant is tax free only to the extent (that) <del>It doesn't exceed your qualified education expenses;</del> it isn't designated or earmarked for other purposes (such as room and board)

so:

> A scholarship or fellowship grant is tax free only *to the extent (that)* it isn't designated or earmarked for other purposes (such as room and board)

And to simplify further:

> A scholarship or fellowship grant is tax free *if* it isn't designated or earmarked for other purposes (such as room and board).

But keep in mind that taxation rules as written are (some say purposely) confusing. It is always advisable to contact the IRS or a tax professional, since there may be other conditions you are not aware of.